# Searching for the file name in html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I have this code:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/basic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/basic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-12 sortableContainer">
<form class="dropzone dpz-multiple-files dz-clickable ui-sortable dz-started" id="dpz-multiple-files" action="http://localhost/psCMS2/admin/dropZoneUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="border:1px solid #000;">
   <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div>
   <div class="dz-preview dz-complete dz-image-preview">
      <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="index.html" src="http://localhost/psCMS2/assets/uploads/index.html"></div>
      <div class="dz-details">
         <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size=""><strong>0</strong> b</span></div>
         <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name="">index.html</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-success-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Check</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <path d="M23.5,31.8431458 L17.5852419,25.9283877 C16.0248253,24.3679711 13.4910294,24.366835 11.9289322,25.9289322 C10.3700136,27.4878508 10.3665912,30.0234455 11.9283877,31.5852419 L20.4147581,40.0716123 C20.5133999,40.1702541 20.6159315,40.2626649 20.7218615,40.3488435 C22.2835669,41.8725651 24.794234,41.8626202 26.3461564,40.3106978 L43.3106978,23.3461564 C44.8771021,21.7797521 44.8758057,19.2483887 43.3137085,17.6862915 C41.7547899,16.1273729 39.2176035,16.1255422 37.6538436,17.6893022 L23.5,31.8431458 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" stroke="#747474" fill-opacity="0.816519475" fill="#FFFFFF" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-error-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Error</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <g id="Check-+-Oval-2" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" stroke="#747474" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0.816519475">
                  <path d="M32.6568542,29 L38.3106978,23.3461564 C39.8771021,21.7797521 39.8758057,19.2483887 38.3137085,17.6862915 C36.7547899,16.1273729 34.2176035,16.1255422 32.6538436,17.6893022 L27,23.3431458 L21.3461564,17.6893022 C19.7823965,16.1255422 17.2452101,16.1273729 15.6862915,17.6862915 C14.1241943,19.2483887 14.1228979,21.7797521 15.6893022,23.3461564 L21.3431458,29 L15.6893022,34.6538436 C14.1228979,36.2202479 14.1241943,38.7516113 15.6862915,40.3137085 C17.2452101,41.8726271 19.7823965,41.8744578 21.3461564,40.3106978 L27,34.6568542 L32.6538436,40.3106978 C34.2176035,41.8744578 36.7547899,41.8726271 38.3137085,40.3137085 C39.8758057,38.7516113 39.8771021,36.2202479 38.3106978,34.6538436 L32.6568542,29 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
               </g>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <button> Remove file </button>
   </div>
   <div class="dz-preview dz-complete dz-image-preview">
      <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt=".DS_Store" src="http://localhost/psCMS2/assets/uploads/.DS_Store"></div>
      <div class="dz-details">
         <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size=""><strong>8.2</strong> KB</span></div>
         <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name="">.DS_Store</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-success-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Check</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <path d="M23.5,31.8431458 L17.5852419,25.9283877 C16.0248253,24.3679711 13.4910294,24.366835 11.9289322,25.9289322 C10.3700136,27.4878508 10.3665912,30.0234455 11.9283877,31.5852419 L20.4147581,40.0716123 C20.5133999,40.1702541 20.6159315,40.2626649 20.7218615,40.3488435 C22.2835669,41.8725651 24.794234,41.8626202 26.3461564,40.3106978 L43.3106978,23.3461564 C44.8771021,21.7797521 44.8758057,19.2483887 43.3137085,17.6862915 C41.7547899,16.1273729 39.2176035,16.1255422 37.6538436,17.6893022 L23.5,31.8431458 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" stroke="#747474" fill-opacity="0.816519475" fill="#FFFFFF" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-error-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Error</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <g id="Check-+-Oval-2" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" stroke="#747474" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0.816519475">
                  <path d="M32.6568542,29 L38.3106978,23.3461564 C39.8771021,21.7797521 39.8758057,19.2483887 38.3137085,17.6862915 C36.7547899,16.1273729 34.2176035,16.1255422 32.6538436,17.6893022 L27,23.3431458 L21.3461564,17.6893022 C19.7823965,16.1255422 17.2452101,16.1273729 15.6862915,17.6862915 C14.1241943,19.2483887 14.1228979,21.7797521 15.6893022,23.3461564 L21.3431458,29 L15.6893022,34.6538436 C14.1228979,36.2202479 14.1241943,38.7516113 15.6862915,40.3137085 C17.2452101,41.8726271 19.7823965,41.8744578 21.3461564,40.3106978 L27,34.6568542 L32.6538436,40.3106978 C34.2176035,41.8744578 36.7547899,41.8726271 38.3137085,40.3137085 C39.8758057,38.7516113 39.8771021,36.2202479 38.3106978,34.6538436 L32.6568542,29 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
               </g>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <button> Remove file </button>
   </div>
   <div class="dz-preview dz-complete dz-image-preview">
      <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="bla.jpg" src="http://localhost/psCMS2/assets/uploads/bla.jpg"></div>
      <div class="dz-details">
         <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size=""><strong>3.4</strong> MB</span></div>
         <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name="">bla.jpg</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-success-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Check</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <path d="M23.5,31.8431458 L17.5852419,25.9283877 C16.0248253,24.3679711 13.4910294,24.366835 11.9289322,25.9289322 C10.3700136,27.4878508 10.3665912,30.0234455 11.9283877,31.5852419 L20.4147581,40.0716123 C20.5133999,40.1702541 20.6159315,40.2626649 20.7218615,40.3488435 C22.2835669,41.8725651 24.794234,41.8626202 26.3461564,40.3106978 L43.3106978,23.3461564 C44.8771021,21.7797521 44.8758057,19.2483887 43.3137085,17.6862915 C41.7547899,16.1273729 39.2176035,16.1255422 37.6538436,17.6893022 L23.5,31.8431458 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" stroke="#747474" fill-opacity="0.816519475" fill="#FFFFFF" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-error-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Error</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <g id="Check-+-Oval-2" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" stroke="#747474" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0.816519475">
                  <path d="M32.6568542,29 L38.3106978,23.3461564 C39.8771021,21.7797521 39.8758057,19.2483887 38.3137085,17.6862915 C36.7547899,16.1273729 34.2176035,16.1255422 32.6538436,17.6893022 L27,23.3431458 L21.3461564,17.6893022 C19.7823965,16.1255422 17.2452101,16.1273729 15.6862915,17.6862915 C14.1241943,19.2483887 14.1228979,21.7797521 15.6893022,23.3461564 L21.3431458,29 L15.6893022,34.6538436 C14.1228979,36.2202479 14.1241943,38.7516113 15.6862915,40.3137085 C17.2452101,41.8726271 19.7823965,41.8744578 21.3461564,40.3106978 L27,34.6568542 L32.6538436,40.3106978 C34.2176035,41.8744578 36.7547899,41.8726271 38.3137085,40.3137085 C39.8758057,38.7516113 39.8771021,36.2202479 38.3106978,34.6538436 L32.6568542,29 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
               </g>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <button> Remove file </button>
   </div>
   <div class="dz-preview dz-complete dz-image-preview">
      <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt=".htaccess" src="http://localhost/psCMS2/assets/uploads/.htaccess"></div>
      <div class="dz-details">
         <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size=""><strong>0.1</strong> KB</span></div>
         <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name="">.htaccess</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-success-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Check</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <path d="M23.5,31.8431458 L17.5852419,25.9283877 C16.0248253,24.3679711 13.4910294,24.366835 11.9289322,25.9289322 C10.3700136,27.4878508 10.3665912,30.0234455 11.9283877,31.5852419 L20.4147581,40.0716123 C20.5133999,40.1702541 20.6159315,40.2626649 20.7218615,40.3488435 C22.2835669,41.8725651 24.794234,41.8626202 26.3461564,40.3106978 L43.3106978,23.3461564 C44.8771021,21.7797521 44.8758057,19.2483887 43.3137085,17.6862915 C41.7547899,16.1273729 39.2176035,16.1255422 37.6538436,17.6893022 L23.5,31.8431458 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" stroke="#747474" fill-opacity="0.816519475" fill="#FFFFFF" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-error-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Error</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <g id="Check-+-Oval-2" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" stroke="#747474" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0.816519475">
                  <path d="M32.6568542,29 L38.3106978,23.3461564 C39.8771021,21.7797521 39.8758057,19.2483887 38.3137085,17.6862915 C36.7547899,16.1273729 34.2176035,16.1255422 32.6538436,17.6893022 L27,23.3431458 L21.3461564,17.6893022 C19.7823965,16.1255422 17.2452101,16.1273729 15.6862915,17.6862915 C14.1241943,19.2483887 14.1228979,21.7797521 15.6893022,23.3461564 L21.3431458,29 L15.6893022,34.6538436 C14.1228979,36.2202479 14.1241943,38.7516113 15.6862915,40.3137085 C17.2452101,41.8726271 19.7823965,41.8744578 21.3461564,40.3106978 L27,34.6568542 L32.6538436,40.3106978 C34.2176035,41.8744578 36.7547899,41.8726271 38.3137085,40.3137085 C39.8758057,38.7516113 39.8771021,36.2202479 38.3106978,34.6538436 L32.6568542,29 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
               </g>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <button> Remove file </button>
   </div>
</form>
<br>
<center>
   <button id="submit-all" style="height: 40px;"> Upload All the files</button>
</center>
</div>
<script>




    $(function () {
            $(".dropzone").sortable({
                items: '.dz-preview',
                cursor: 'move',
                opacity: 0.5,
                containment: '.dropzone',
                distance: 20,
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                update: function(event, ui){
                    //console.log(ui);

                    //alert('PRZENOSZE');
                    var myDropzone = Dropzone.getElement(".dpz-multiple-files");
                    var arr = myDropzone.files;
                    console.log(myDropzone);
                    alert(myDropzone);

                    var itemOrder = $('.dropzone').sortable("toArray");
                    for (var i = 0; i < itemOrder.length; i++) {

                        //alert("Position: " + i + " ID: " + itemOrder[i]);
                    }
                }
            });
```

To the above , there are elements downloaded using dropzoneJS (this is done and works correctly for me).
In function: $(".dropzone").sortable I need to get the file name from the html code above.
How to do it?

File name is here: file name

HTML Formated: https://pastebin.com/YVDwmHD4

**UPDATE 2**

```
From function: $(function () {
        $(".dropzone").sortable({
            items: '.dz-preview',
            cursor: 'move',
            opacity: 0.5,
            containment: '.dropzone',
            distance: 20,
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            update: function (event, ui) {
                //console.log(ui);

                //alert('PRZENOSZE');
                var myDropzone = Dropzone.getElement(".dpz-multiple-files");
                var arr = myDropzone.files;
                console.log(myDropzone);


                var itemOrder = $('.dropzone').sortable("toArray");
                for (var i = 0; i < itemOrder.length; i++) {

                    //alert("Position: " + i + " ID: " + itemOrder[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Inside this function I need to download all filenames from the html code

Comment: What do you have tried so far?

Comment: I sat yesterday on it all day and today and I have no idea what to do :(

Comment: Are you looking for that svg files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
$(".dropzone").sortable({
items: '.dz-preview',
cursor: 'move',
opacity: 0.5,
containment: '.dropzone',
distance: 20,
tolerance: 'pointer',
update: function(event, ui){
//console.log(ui);
//alert('PRZENOSZE');
$( ".dz-filename span" ).each(function( index ) { 
alert( index + ": " + $( this ).text() ); 
});
var myDropzone = Dropzone.getElement(".dpz-multiple-files");
var arr = myDropzone.files;
console.log(myDropzone);
alert(myDropzone);
var itemOrder = $('.dropzone').sortable("toArray");
for (var i = 0; i < itemOrder.length; i++) {
//alert("Position: " + i + " ID: " + itemOrder[i]);
}
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/basic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/basic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-12 sortableContainer">
<form class="dropzone dpz-multiple-files dz-clickable ui-sortable dz-started" id="dpz-multiple-files" action="http://localhost/psCMS2/admin/dropZoneUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="border:1px solid #000;">
   <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div>
   <div class="dz-preview dz-complete dz-image-preview">
      <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="index.html" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"></div>
      <div class="dz-details">
         <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size=""><strong>0</strong> b</span></div>
         <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name="">index.html</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-success-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Check</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <path d="M23.5,31.8431458 L17.5852419,25.9283877 C16.0248253,24.3679711 13.4910294,24.366835 11.9289322,25.9289322 C10.3700136,27.4878508 10.3665912,30.0234455 11.9283877,31.5852419 L20.4147581,40.0716123 C20.5133999,40.1702541 20.6159315,40.2626649 20.7218615,40.3488435 C22.2835669,41.8725651 24.794234,41.8626202 26.3461564,40.3106978 L43.3106978,23.3461564 C44.8771021,21.7797521 44.8758057,19.2483887 43.3137085,17.6862915 C41.7547899,16.1273729 39.2176035,16.1255422 37.6538436,17.6893022 L23.5,31.8431458 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" stroke="#747474" fill-opacity="0.816519475" fill="#FFFFFF" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-error-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Error</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <g id="Check-+-Oval-2" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" stroke="#747474" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0.816519475">
                  <path d="M32.6568542,29 L38.3106978,23.3461564 C39.8771021,21.7797521 39.8758057,19.2483887 38.3137085,17.6862915 C36.7547899,16.1273729 34.2176035,16.1255422 32.6538436,17.6893022 L27,23.3431458 L21.3461564,17.6893022 C19.7823965,16.1255422 17.2452101,16.1273729 15.6862915,17.6862915 C14.1241943,19.2483887 14.1228979,21.7797521 15.6893022,23.3461564 L21.3431458,29 L15.6893022,34.6538436 C14.1228979,36.2202479 14.1241943,38.7516113 15.6862915,40.3137085 C17.2452101,41.8726271 19.7823965,41.8744578 21.3461564,40.3106978 L27,34.6568542 L32.6538436,40.3106978 C34.2176035,41.8744578 36.7547899,41.8726271 38.3137085,40.3137085 C39.8758057,38.7516113 39.8771021,36.2202479 38.3106978,34.6538436 L32.6568542,29 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
               </g>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <button> Remove file </button>
   </div>
   <div class="dz-preview dz-complete dz-image-preview">
      <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt=".DS_Store" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png"></div>
      <div class="dz-details">
         <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size=""><strong>8.2</strong> KB</span></div>
         <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name="">.DS_Store</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-success-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Check</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <path d="M23.5,31.8431458 L17.5852419,25.9283877 C16.0248253,24.3679711 13.4910294,24.366835 11.9289322,25.9289322 C10.3700136,27.4878508 10.3665912,30.0234455 11.9283877,31.5852419 L20.4147581,40.0716123 C20.5133999,40.1702541 20.6159315,40.2626649 20.7218615,40.3488435 C22.2835669,41.8725651 24.794234,41.8626202 26.3461564,40.3106978 L43.3106978,23.3461564 C44.8771021,21.7797521 44.8758057,19.2483887 43.3137085,17.6862915 C41.7547899,16.1273729 39.2176035,16.1255422 37.6538436,17.6893022 L23.5,31.8431458 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" stroke="#747474" fill-opacity="0.816519475" fill="#FFFFFF" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-error-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Error</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <g id="Check-+-Oval-2" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" stroke="#747474" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0.816519475">
                  <path d="M32.6568542,29 L38.3106978,23.3461564 C39.8771021,21.7797521 39.8758057,19.2483887 38.3137085,17.6862915 C36.7547899,16.1273729 34.2176035,16.1255422 32.6538436,17.6893022 L27,23.3431458 L21.3461564,17.6893022 C19.7823965,16.1255422 17.2452101,16.1273729 15.6862915,17.6862915 C14.1241943,19.2483887 14.1228979,21.7797521 15.6893022,23.3461564 L21.3431458,29 L15.6893022,34.6538436 C14.1228979,36.2202479 14.1241943,38.7516113 15.6862915,40.3137085 C17.2452101,41.8726271 19.7823965,41.8744578 21.3461564,40.3106978 L27,34.6568542 L32.6538436,40.3106978 C34.2176035,41.8744578 36.7547899,41.8726271 38.3137085,40.3137085 C39.8758057,38.7516113 39.8771021,36.2202479 38.3106978,34.6538436 L32.6568542,29 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
               </g>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <button> Remove file </button>
   </div>
   <div class="dz-preview dz-complete dz-image-preview">
      <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="bla.jpg" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/girl.png"></div>
      <div class="dz-details">
         <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size=""><strong>3.4</strong> MB</span></div>
         <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name="">bla.jpg</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-success-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Check</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <path d="M23.5,31.8431458 L17.5852419,25.9283877 C16.0248253,24.3679711 13.4910294,24.366835 11.9289322,25.9289322 C10.3700136,27.4878508 10.3665912,30.0234455 11.9283877,31.5852419 L20.4147581,40.0716123 C20.5133999,40.1702541 20.6159315,40.2626649 20.7218615,40.3488435 C22.2835669,41.8725651 24.794234,41.8626202 26.3461564,40.3106978 L43.3106978,23.3461564 C44.8771021,21.7797521 44.8758057,19.2483887 43.3137085,17.6862915 C41.7547899,16.1273729 39.2176035,16.1255422 37.6538436,17.6893022 L23.5,31.8431458 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" stroke="#747474" fill-opacity="0.816519475" fill="#FFFFFF" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-error-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Error</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <g id="Check-+-Oval-2" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" stroke="#747474" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0.816519475">
                  <path d="M32.6568542,29 L38.3106978,23.3461564 C39.8771021,21.7797521 39.8758057,19.2483887 38.3137085,17.6862915 C36.7547899,16.1273729 34.2176035,16.1255422 32.6538436,17.6893022 L27,23.3431458 L21.3461564,17.6893022 C19.7823965,16.1255422 17.2452101,16.1273729 15.6862915,17.6862915 C14.1241943,19.2483887 14.1228979,21.7797521 15.6893022,23.3461564 L21.3431458,29 L15.6893022,34.6538436 C14.1228979,36.2202479 14.1241943,38.7516113 15.6862915,40.3137085 C17.2452101,41.8726271 19.7823965,41.8744578 21.3461564,40.3106978 L27,34.6568542 L32.6538436,40.3106978 C34.2176035,41.8744578 36.7547899,41.8726271 38.3137085,40.3137085 C39.8758057,38.7516113 39.8771021,36.2202479 38.3106978,34.6538436 L32.6568542,29 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
               </g>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <button> Remove file </button>
   </div>
   <div class="dz-preview dz-complete dz-image-preview">
      <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt=".htaccess" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/peppers.png"></div>
      <div class="dz-details">
         <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size=""><strong>0.1</strong> KB</span></div>
         <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name="">.htaccess</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage=""></span></div>
      <div class="dz-success-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Check</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <path d="M23.5,31.8431458 L17.5852419,25.9283877 C16.0248253,24.3679711 13.4910294,24.366835 11.9289322,25.9289322 C10.3700136,27.4878508 10.3665912,30.0234455 11.9283877,31.5852419 L20.4147581,40.0716123 C20.5133999,40.1702541 20.6159315,40.2626649 20.7218615,40.3488435 C22.2835669,41.8725651 24.794234,41.8626202 26.3461564,40.3106978 L43.3106978,23.3461564 C44.8771021,21.7797521 44.8758057,19.2483887 43.3137085,17.6862915 C41.7547899,16.1273729 39.2176035,16.1255422 37.6538436,17.6893022 L23.5,31.8431458 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" stroke="#747474" fill-opacity="0.816519475" fill="#FFFFFF" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="dz-error-mark">
         <svg width="54px" height="54px" viewBox="0 0 54 54" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
            <title>Error</title>
            <defs></defs>
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
               <g id="Check-+-Oval-2" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" stroke="#747474" stroke-opacity="0.198794158" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0.816519475">
                  <path d="M32.6568542,29 L38.3106978,23.3461564 C39.8771021,21.7797521 39.8758057,19.2483887 38.3137085,17.6862915 C36.7547899,16.1273729 34.2176035,16.1255422 32.6538436,17.6893022 L27,23.3431458 L21.3461564,17.6893022 C19.7823965,16.1255422 17.2452101,16.1273729 15.6862915,17.6862915 C14.1241943,19.2483887 14.1228979,21.7797521 15.6893022,23.3461564 L21.3431458,29 L15.6893022,34.6538436 C14.1228979,36.2202479 14.1241943,38.7516113 15.6862915,40.3137085 C17.2452101,41.8726271 19.7823965,41.8744578 21.3461564,40.3106978 L27,34.6568542 L32.6538436,40.3106978 C34.2176035,41.8744578 36.7547899,41.8726271 38.3137085,40.3137085 C39.8758057,38.7516113 39.8771021,36.2202479 38.3106978,34.6538436 L32.6568542,29 Z M27,53 C41.3594035,53 53,41.3594035 53,27 C53,12.6405965 41.3594035,1 27,1 C12.6405965,1 1,12.6405965 1,27 C1,41.3594035 12.6405965,53 27,53 Z" id="Oval-2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
               </g>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <button> Remove file </button>
   </div>
</form>
<br>
<center>
   <button id="submit-all" style="height: 40px;"> Upload All the files</button>
</center>
</div>
<script>

</script>
```

```
$( ".dz-filename span" ).each(function( index ) { 
alert( index + ": " + $( this ).text() ); 
});
```

Simply iterate over the filename element.

Comment: @trafiks `.sortable` is not from dropzoneJS

Comment: Yes, I know. I have add this in my project. I need to display in js alert (myFileNamesInDropZone) - after changing any element in the dropzone.

Comment: Are you using bootsrap ? Should find from which library `sortable ` comes from.

Comment: I need to display the names of files in the alert in the order they are currently in the dropzone. Yes, bootstrap and dropzone.min.js, jQuery and jquery-ui.js

Comment: Now the above snippet is error free. Do want to upload new files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181340/discussion-between-trafiks-and-sumesh-tg).